# GUI for computer vision app

Tags: java, qt, opencv, image-processing, user-interface

I'd like some opinions please on a GUI for my computer vision application.  I have written an application in C++ using OpenCV which captures video from a high speed camera, carries out some image processing on the images and displays the results to a HighGUI window.  I find myself tweaking variables on a regular basis and have therefore decided it would be easier and quicker to tweak those variables using a GUI on the fly.  I have a few options:

- Create a Java GUI that can talk to my C++ computer vision app using sockets
- Integrate my application within a QT GUI
- Use native Windows calls (e.g. MFC)

Which do you you guys think is my best option, bearing in mind that the GUI or sockets must not detract from the performance of the image processing part of the application?

(My target OS is Windows)

Many thanks in advance everyone for your inputs.

Comment: Use Microsoft C++ CLR. Create the interface using Windows Forms. Integrate OpenCV code into the same C++ project. i.e. mix the managed Windows Forms code with unmanaged OpenCV code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider option 1 or 2, 3 seams definitely the worst, because you have to write all related to gui code on your own and it will be not portable.
1. Instead of this option i would consider creating GUI in Java and putting whole c++ code into library and using it in Java or even using native c++ code in Java. This solution should be faster than sending data via sockets.
2. QT seams the best option - it has big community, lot of tutorials and partially is integrated with OpenCV(http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_qt_new_functions.html). Another advantage is that application created with QT and OpenCV should run on many operation systems. Also you may use Qt Creator or visual studio qt plugin to create gui.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to deal with platform native code on Windows. The API is archaic, just like MFC is.

I don't think there's any benefit to isolating the GUI in a separate process.

I'd suggest using Qt Quick. You can very efficiently display images from OpenCV by binding them to a texture on a trivial scene graph item. You get a fluid, modern user interface and performant integration with OpenCV at the same time. It all blends, so to speak.

The easiest way to integrate your variables with QML is by using model-view paradigm. You can expose the variables form C++ by reimplementing a `QAbstractListModel`. The variable's value could be bound to the edit and display roles. The variable's name can be exposed as an additional role, called for example `name`. It's then a simple matter to use a ListView in Qt Quick to display the variable list and allow it to be tweaked at runtime. You can easily have "fancy" delegates for your items, say sliders.